# Cakephp and Sweet Alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cakephp, sweetalert

I have a question about cakephp and sweet alert.
Are you able to replace, and instead of the standard Flash Message, give Sweet Alert? I have already managed to give Sweet Alert the confirmation of deleting the record, but I do not know how I can handle it when it saves data (for example in edit.ctp) and after saving it brings me to index.ctp (here I want Sweet Jump to pop out).

At the confirmation of removal I used **cakephp-3-sweet-alert-helper** by **falco442**.

This is my edit method:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $contact = $this->Contacts->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Departments']
    ]);
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $contact = $this->Contacts->patchEntity($contact, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Contacts->save($contact)) {
            $this->Flash->success('Contact saved');

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The contact could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $users = $this->Contacts->Users->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('contact', 'users'));
}
```

How can I replace this **$this->Flash->success('Your Success Message.');** with an alert from SWAL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave controller code as is.

But you should update flash message templates at `src/Template/Element/Flash/`.

By default, CakePHP outputs `<div>`, you should replace it with `<script>swal("Hello world!");</script>`

Comment: Yes, thank you. It's work. I forget to add $this->Flash->render() to default.ctp

Answer (score 0):

here you can set sweet alert javascript

Path: src/Template/Element/Flash
success.ctp
error.ctp

first thing use sweet alert js and css 

swal({
  title: "Success",
  text: "Successfully created",
  icon: "success",
});